# how to add custom active class to sidebar menu of dashboard in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dashboard

I have created a sidebar component as `sidebar.js` in which there is a list of sidebar menu

```
<ul>
     <Link href='/Home' passHref>
      <li className=`${styles.listitem} ${styles.active}`>Home</li>
     </Link>
     <Link href='/Profile' passHref>
      <li className=`${styles.listitem}`>Profile</li>
     </Link>
     <Link href='/About' passHref>
      <li className=`${styles.listitem}`>About</li>
     </Link>
     <Link href='/Blogs' passHref>
      <li className=`${styles.listitem}`>Blogs</li>
     </Link>
</ul>
```

and to style this component I have created `sidebar.modules.css` file in which there is an active class styling as

```
.active {
background: #0077bb;
}
```

but I don't want it like this, I want to add an active class to it when I call this component from the parent screen while passing an active class as a prop like this

```
const Home = () =>{
returns(
<sidebar homeActive = 'active' />
)
}
```

like this for all the pages how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li activeClassName={styles.active}>
   <NavLink to='/Home'>
    Home
   </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li activeClassName={styles.active}>
   <NavLink to='/Profile'>
    Profile
   </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li activeClassName={styles.active}>
   <NavLink to='/About'>
    About
   </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li activeClassName={styles.active}>
   <NavLink to='/Blogs'>
    Profile
   </Blogs>
  </li>
</ul>
```

P.S
In React Router v6, activeClassName will be removed and you should use the function className to apply classnames to either active or inactive NavLink components.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer??? @Zuriel

Comment: @ZurielS.G. OP is using Next.js that provides [its own built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), it doesn't use React Router.

Comment: I was sure that he use router. Next don't have an official active class.
There is a work around.
Use ternary conditional in the class name
https://dev.to/yuridevat/how-to-add-styling-to-an-active-link-in-nextjs-593e